# Save Browser Cached Image from <img> tag without using src attribute

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsoup, browser-cache

Suppose you have a website,

*example.com*

and you have some images on it which are resized to very low quality. When you click an image, you go to a 'view_image' page, for e.g.

*example.com/view?image=image_related_temp_code*

On this page, Image is loaded in full quality. But, if you check its `src` attribute through Chrome Dev Console for downloading/browsing that `src` link, you get another image saying Go Back as text, which probably prohibits you from downloading the file with direct/hot link. So, it means you can't get the image through `src` link. Also, `src` changes each time you refresh the webpage.

**My question**: How will you use Java / Jsoup / Javascript in such a way that you can get and save the cached image directly from webpage or browser contents without using the `src` attribute.

I tried using Jsoup only. I performed a Jsoup `connect()` and `get()`, searched the `<img>` tag using appropriate class combinations through Jsoup-Document. and implemented `getSRC()` method, and implemented `srcToFile()` method which uses `Files.copy()` method to save image. But, until now, I am only able to get Go Back image again and again.

I can not share website URL because it is hosted locally on college's server. This is probably due to a `.htaccess` file, is it possible to save cached image somehow?

Comment: Is it possible to do a javascript injection, via Chrome  Inspector Console?

Comment: @Krishnakumar_Muraleedharan can we do it through javascript injection. I am just curious.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML contains `<img src='#nothingToKnow'>`.

In body.onload() you read the image via Ajax-call from the server.

But the server has to send base64(imagedata). With the result string you change your image to `document.getElementById("theImgId").src = 'data:image/png;base64,'+resultstring;`

Comment: for javascript, my load.js needs to access that URL, let it load the URL in a frame container, after waiting for about 20sec, get the `<img>` tags, get `src` where it fails to reach actual image. I need to get the image that is currently cached.